# How to create a loop expression tree

Tags: c#, loops, .net-core, expression-trees

I am trying to create an expression tree that would generate this method:

```
public static int Print(int i) {
            int cnt = 0;
            int sum = 0;
            while (true) {
                if (cnt >= i) {
                    Console.WriteLine(sum);
                    break;
                }
                sum = sum + cnt;
                cnt++;
            }
           return sum;
        }
```

I do not understand how the `LabelTarget` works.In my case there is no value that i want to jump to...I do not understand why it does require a `type`.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static  Func<int,int> MakeExpression() {
            //input
            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int));
            //define local variables and initialize them
            Expression cntVarExpr = Expression.Variable(typeof(int),"cnt");
            Expression sumVarExpr = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "sum");

            Expression initCntExpr = Expression.Assign(cntVarExpr, Expression.Constant(0));
            Expression initSumExpr = Expression.Assign(sumVarExpr, Expression.Constant(0));

            //loop condition
            Expression condExpr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(cntVarExpr, parameter);
            //block if true
            MethodInfo method = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine",new Type[] { typeof(int)});
            Expression printExpr = Expression.Call(null, method,cntVarExpr); //static method

            LabelTarget label = Expression.Label(typeof(int)); //am not sure about this one ? what
            Expression bkExpr = Expression.Break(label, sumVarExpr);
            BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(printExpr, bkExpr);

            //loop body
            Expression ifExpr = Expression.IfThen(condExpr, block);
            Expression addExpr = Expression.AddAssign(sumVarExpr,cntVarExpr);
            Expression incrExpr = Expression.Add(cntVarExpr, Expression.Constant(1));
            BlockExpression loopBodyExpr = Expression.Block(ifExpr, addExpr,incrExpr);
            LoopExpression loopExpr = Expression.Loop(loopBodyExpr);

            //method body

            Expression returnExpr = Expression.Return(label, sumVarExpr,typeof(int));

            //final expression
            BlockExpression bigExpression = Expression.Block(initCntExpr, initSumExpr, loopExpr, returnExpr);


            var meth = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(bigExpression,parameter).Compile();
            return meth;
        }
```

I keep getting this error:

```
'variable 'cnt' of type 'System.Int32' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'
```

Comment: You don't need to use the `Type` parameter to `Expression.Label`. `LabelExpression` allows the label itself to return a value, which is not a concept in C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `VariableExpression` in a block, you have to pass that variable into the `variables` parameter of `Expression.Block`. This is what's causing your error.

I'm afraid I didn't have time to go through your code in detail, but I rewrote your C# using expressions:

```
var i = Expression.Parameter(typeof(int), "i");
var cnt = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "cnt");
var sum = Expression.Variable(typeof(int), "sum");

var writeLineMethod = typeof(Console).GetMethod("WriteLine", new[] { typeof(object) });

var breakLabel = Expression.Label("break");
var loop = Expression.Loop(
    Expression.Block(
        Expression.IfThen(
            Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(cnt, i),
            Expression.Block(
                Expression.Call(writeLineMethod, Expression.Convert(sum, typeof(object))),
                Expression.Break(breakLabel))),
        Expression.AddAssign(sum, cnt),
        Expression.PostIncrementAssign(cnt)),
    breakLabel);

var block = Expression.Block(new[] { cnt, sum },
    Expression.Assign(cnt, Expression.Constant(0)),
    Expression.Assign(sum, Expression.Constant(0)),
    loop,
    sum);

var method = Expression.Lambda<Func<int, int>>(block, new[] { i }).Compile();
```

Comment: Could you explain the `new[] {cnt,sum}` in the `block` variable ? And also the last line the need of `new[]{i}` ? (Also why you do not need the `Return`) ?If not , is there any resource that details on how to use `ETrees`? `Msdn` does not provide rich examples for some expressions.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian When you use a `VariableExpression` in a block, you need to pass that same `VariableExpression` into the `variables` parameter of `Expression.Block`. It isn't enough to simply use a variable inside a block: you have to tell the block that you're going to use that variable. For the `new[] { i }`, when you create a `LambdaExpression`, you need to say what the parameters to the lambda are. This lambda has a single input, `i`, so we pass that in a single-element array to `Expression.Lambda`'s `parameters` parameter.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian No, you do not need return statements. The last expression in a block is the return value from the block. Likewise the last expression in a lambda is the return value from that lambda. This is what I have `sum` as the last item in the block -- this becomes the return value from the block, and the block's return value becomes the return value from the lambda.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian you just have to write C#, let the compiler compile it into expressions, and inspect what it did. If you write e.g. `Expression<Func<string, string> x = () => ....`, you can then inspect `x` to see what the compiler did. Also have a look at the `DebugView` property in the debugger, which gives you a textual representation of the expression tree. For the more complex stuff (and blocks, which you can't test using `Expression<Func<..>>..`), I learnt by trial-and-error, random blog posts, and this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression

Comment: But does it matter the position where you put the `variables` parameter inside a `block`? In our case could you have placed `new []{sum,cnt}` after the `assignment expressions?` And also , following this logic wouldn't the `block` inside the `loop` variable had to start with `new[]{sum,cnt}` since you are actively using them ?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian Yes. It's this overload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.block?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_Block_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable_System_Linq_Expressions_ParameterExpression__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression___ . It takes an `IEnumerable<ParameterExpression>`, which is the variables (the `new[] { sum, cnt }`, and a `params Expression[]` which is the block members. You could have written `Expression.Block(new[] { sum, cnt }, new[] { Expression.Assign..... sum })` instead.

Comment: But the `Block` inside the `loop` variable didn't need the `sum` and `cnt` added since it was already defined in a bigger scope -> the `block` variable right?

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian correct. If a variable is in scope in an outer block, it's automatically in scope in an inner block.